# React.JS can't add html tags

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, and trying to understand why I can't add an HTML tag to my render method

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      My App
      <Projects projects={this.state.projects}/>
    </div>
  );
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      My App
      <Projects projects={this.state.projects}/>
    </div>
    <h1> hello world </h1>
  );
}
```

how come this work but if I add `</h1> hello world </h1>` into the function it would no longer work?

Comment: `</h1>hello world</h1>` starts with a closing tag; `<h1>hello world</h1>` is the proper notation... while it needs to reside within that `<div>`, in order to return a single node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render functions can only return one HTML tag, so you should include all on one div for example

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      My App
      <Projects projects={this.state.projects}/>
      <h1> hello world </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Fragment.
A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.
https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```